# Save modified shape contents to PostGIS using Geotools fails with NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, exception, pom.xml, geotools

I am modifying a shape file and I want to save the modified version in the database using Geotools. However the code works fine till shapefile modification, but fails at the point of database setup.

Here is the code:

```
FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(new File("/abc.shp"));
        logger.debug("starting check");
        SimpleFeatureType schema = ds.getSchema();
        // create new schema
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName(schema.getName());
        builder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());
        builder.addAll(schema.getAttributeDescriptors());
        // add new attribute(s)
        builder.add("shapeID", String.class);
        // build new schema
        SimpleFeatureType nSchema = builder.buildFeatureType();

        logger.debug("Adding column attr to shpfile");
        // loop through features adding new attribute
        List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
        try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures().features()) {
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
                SimpleFeature f2 = DataUtilities.reType(nSchema, f);
                f2.setAttribute("shapeID", "SHP1234");
                System.out.println(f2);
                features.add(f2);
            }
        }
        Properties params = new Properties();
       // Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user", "user1");
        params.put("passwd", "postgres");
        params.put("port", "5432");
        params.put("host", "127.0.0.1");
        params.put("database", "test");
        params.put("dbtype", "postgres");
        params.put(PostgisDataStoreFactory.LOOSEBBOX, true );

        logger.debug("Entering the critical point");

        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
        SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource("table_name"); //table name already present in PostGIS

        //dataStore.createSchema(nSchema);  //Creates a new table

        if (source instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
            SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) source;
            store.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(features));

           logger.debug("Stored in database successfully");
        } else {
            logger.error("Unable to write to database");
        }
    }
```

The error stack trace is as follows.

```
2018-10-02 16:54:52 DEBUG Initmain:38 - starting check
2018-10-02 16:54:56 DEBUG Initmain:41 - starting check
2018-10-02 16:54:58 DEBUG Initmain:53 - Adding column attr to shpfile
2018-10-02 16:54:58 DEBUG Initmain:75 - Entering the critical point
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.geoshapesave.saveShape.main(saveShape.java:78)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 16.638s
Finished at: Tue Oct 02 16:55:00 CEST 2018
Final Memory: 8M/76M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project GeoDemo: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project GeoDemo: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
    ... 21 more
```

Also attaching the pom.xml based on the above stack trace inputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>GeoDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>20-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.geosolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoserver-manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools.jdbc/gt-jdbc-postgis -->
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
<!--      <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>-->

        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>boundless</id>
          <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT** Updated error logs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/data/jdbc/JDBCDataStore
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisDataStoreFactory.createDataStoreInternal(PostgisDataStoreFactory.java:237)
    at org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(PostgisDataStoreFactory.java:208)
    at org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(PostgisDataStoreFactory.java:46)
    at org.geotools.data.DataAccessFinder.getDataStore(DataAccessFinder.java:121)
    at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(DataStoreFinder.java:71)
    at org.geotools.geoshapesave.saveShape.main(saveShape.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.data.jdbc.JDBCDataStore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: remove both jts and gt-postgis from your dependencies - both are out of date.

Comment: ur simply super... It worked.. It was due to the jts dependency :)

Comment: the last version of GeoTools uses an upgraded version - http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of that is that GeoTools can not connect to PostGIS and has returned a null `DataStore`. You can add some checks for that condition, the following code works for me with a local PostGIS database.

```
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
if (dataStore == null) {
  System.out.println("Failed to connect to PostGIS");
  System.exit(1);
}
String tableName = nSchema.getTypeName();
boolean exists = false;
String[] names = dataStore.getTypeNames();
for (String name : names) {
  if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(tableName)) {
    exists = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (!exists) {
  dataStore.createSchema(nSchema);
}
SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(tableName);
if (source instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
  SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) source;
  store.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(features));
} else {
  System.err.println("Unable to connect to database");
}
```

For production code you should also decide whether to add to or truncate and replace an existing table.

Comment: Does the dependency postgres jar and local postgres version (version 10.4) should match? The maven dependency I am using is this `gt-jdbc-postgis` and `gt-postgis`.  I'm getting a diff error now after params change..Its updated in the question